# Rally API 2 how to access the PlanEstimate of an Iteration

Tags: rally

I can see and get hold of the 'PlannedVelocity' field which is a user entered field, how do I grab the 'Plan Estimate' details which I can see when editing an iteration. This looks like a calculated field that totals the number of actually contained stories in an iteration.

I have tried the obvious 'PlanEstimate' but is returning nulls, is this actually a field that is available to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is only visible in the UI, and shows rollup value of PlanEstimates of artifacts scheduled for the iteration. [WS API object model](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) does not have this field. Iteration object in WS API has the following attributes:

EndDate,Name,Notes,PlannedVelocity,Project,RevisionHistory,StartDate,Theme,UserIterationCapacities